# JBPM - Hibernate QuerySyntaxException

Tags: hibernate, jbpm

am getting the bellow error trace while attempting a [example](http://people.redhat.com/kverlaen/rewards-3.swf) of JBPM in eclipse ide.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select new org.jbpm.task.query.TaskSummary( t.id, t.taskData.processInstanceId, name.text, subject.text, description.text, t.taskData.status, t.priority, t.taskData.skipable, t.taskData.actualOwner, t.taskData.createdBy, t.taskData.createdOn, t.taskData.activationTime, t.taskData.expirationTime, t.taskData.processId, t.taskData.processSessionId) from org.jbpm.task.Task t left join t.taskData.createdBy left join t.taskData.actualOwner left join t.subjects as subject left join t.descriptions as description left join t.names as name, org.jbpm.task.OrganizationalEntity potentialOwners where t.archived = 0 and ( potentialOwners.id = :userId or potentialOwners.id in () ) and potentialOwners in elements ( t.peopleAssignments.potentialOwners ) and ( name.language = :language or t.names.size = 0 ) and ( subject.language = :language or t.subjects.size = 0 ) and ( description.language = :language or t.descriptions.size = 0 ) and t.taskData.status in ('Created', 'Ready', 'Reserved', 'InProgress', 'Suspended') and t.taskData.expirationTime is null]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:76)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner(TaskServiceSession.java:730)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner(TaskServiceSession.java:711)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.local.LocalTaskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner(LocalTaskService.java:193)
    at org.jbpm.Hello_WorldJUnitTest.testConstraint2(Hello_WorldJUnitTest.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be either:
(1) a mismatch between the hibernate dialect you are using (as defined in your persistence.xml) and the database you are using, which database are you using
(2) a mismatch between the query (as defined in the .orm file) and the version of jBPM you are using (possibly having an older / different version of the .orm file in your classpath)?
(3) an issue with this query on the specific database you are using, if so could you open a JIRA issue and attach as much information as possible?

Kris